# How to create a JsonbCong that writes Date in Number instead of String?

Tags: java, json, wildfly, resteasy, jsonb

Obviously, with Eclipse Yasson `JsonbDateFormat.TIME_IN_MILLIS` annotation returns the date number as string:

```
 import javax.json.bind.annotation.JsonbDateFormat;

 class MyObject { 
    @JsonbDateFormat(JsonbDateFormat.TIME_IN_MILLIS)
    Date myDate;
 }
```

e.g outputs (quoted number)

```
{"myDate":"1234567890"}
```

How can I configure the json-b to omit the quotes around the number (like default behavior with Jackson)?, e.g.:

```
{"myDate":1234567890}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a binding adapter from Date to Long (and vise-versa).

```
public static class DateAdapter implements JsonbAdapter<Date, Long> {

    @Override
    public Long adaptToJson(Date date) {
        return date.getTime();
    }

    @Override
    public Date adaptFromJson(Long ms) {
        return new Date(ms);
    }
}
```

Next, annotate the property with `@JsonbTypeAdapter`.

```
class MyObject { 
    @JsonbTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
    Date myDate;
}
```

Comment: Sometimes getting this (still to investigate what is wrong):
`JSON Binding serialization error javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Problem adapting object of type class java.util.Date to class java.lang.Long in class `

Comment: Can you please provide the cause of this exception, if there is any?

Comment: It turned to be a problem in Eclipse Yasson 1.0.2 (1.0.3 is fine): `Recursive reference has been found in class class java.util.Date`. RestEasy is hidding the root cause unfortunately.